# Bounds for an inequality

Tags: inequality

I am having a problem following a proof in my text.

We want $$n^ke^{-n2^{-k}}<1.$$

The text goes on to say that if $n>k^22^{k+1}$, then our desired inequality holds, I have no idea how to verify this.

I have shown that $n^ke^{-n2^{-k}}<1\Longleftrightarrow \frac{n}{\ln{n}}>k2^k$, but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

BACKGROUND: $n$ is the order of a random tournament $T$ and $k$ is the order of $S$, a sub tournament of $T$. The given inequality is an upper bound on the probability that $T$ contains no vertex that dominates any possible $S$ of order $k$. This result was originally proved by Erdos in 1963. His bound was a little tighter with $n>k^22^k(\ln{2}+\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $n = \alpha k^2 2^{k+1}$ for some $\alpha$ then your condition

$$n >  k 2^k\log n$$

becomes

$$\alpha > \frac{\log\alpha}{2k} + \frac{\log k}{k} + \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\frac{\log 2}{2}$$

Finding the smallest value for $\alpha$ for which this is satisfied is hard as it requires solving a transendental equation (and the result will depend on $k$). If you don't care about the best possible $\alpha$ then the simplest way is to just try some values and see if the ineqality holds for these values. For example try $\alpha = 1$ and see what you get.

Comment: Useful facts: $\frac{\log k}{k}$ is decreasing with $k$ for $k\geq 3$ and $\frac{\log 3}{3} \approx 0.36$.

Comment: I see that this is a way to verify that $n>k^22^{k+1}$ does the job, but if I didn't know the answer ahead of time, how would I derive $n>k^22^{k+1}$ from the fact that $n^ke^{-n2^{-k}}<1$?

Comment: @LaarsHelenius This is a type of problem where the best way imo is to make an educated guess and see where that leads you. From $n > k2^k \log n$ it is reasonable to expect something like $n > k 2^k \beta(k)$. OK lets try this and try to find a good $\beta$ that does the job. Take $n = k2^k \beta(k)$ to get $\beta(k) > \log\beta(k) + \log k + k \log 2$. From this it seem like $\beta = k \alpha(k)$ would be a good choice....and from this $\alpha = \log 2 \gamma(k)$ seems likea good choice (which is Erdos bound if you can show $\gamma \sim 1$ is OK)...and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I suspected there was no analytical approach to this as I kept chasing my tail! Your second to last comment was especially helpful.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius No problem. btw there is possible to write down an analytical solution by using the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function): $n = 1/W(-k^{-1}2^{-k})$. However, this is not very useful as this is not an elementary function so this expression would not tell you much.